# vimperator video jump back/forth by left/right arrow keys

Tags: vimperator

When watching youtube videos, left/right arrows are used to jump back/forth several seconds.

How do I do this with vimperator?

(Oh my bad, is this question too short?)

Comment: https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/70, an issue waiting to be solved.

Comment: This issue still exists. Looks like vimperator hasn't implemented a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that even with vimperator enabled, if you have flash player in focus, vimperator will not be able to interfere with the player's hot keys. That being said, if you are using flash player on youtube, then for as long as it is in focus, left and right keys will work whether vimperator is running or not.

Personally for me if the player is not in focus, arrow keys do not jump back/forth several seconds even without vimperator. However, if they used to for you, may be because you are using the HTML5 player (or in general, if you need to enable site-specific hot keys on any other website) this is how you do it:

1. If you just want to enable them temporarily once, just press the `INSERT` button. The text in the status line should change to `IGNORE ALL KEYS`, in which case vimperator will not interfere with any site-specific hot keys. Pressing `INSERT` again will get back to vimperator normal mode.
2. If you want to make certain websites to permanently ignore vimperator (for instance, I use OneNote online, which is not very vimperator-friendly), then add lines similar to these to your `.vimperatorrc` (on linux it's in your home folder)

```
autocmd LocationChange .*                             js modes.passAllKeys = false
autocmd LocationChange onedrive\\.live\\.com          js modes.passAllKeys = true
```

Replace onedrive url wiht the youtube or the URL of any other website on which you want vimperator to disable itself.

Comment: Yes, late to say, I am using html5 player.

Comment: Then my second solution (pressing INSERT for a current session, or changing the .vimperatorrc for continuous effect) should work